# Getting started with a Picasa Plugin

Tags: api, plugins, picasa, photo-management

Does anyone here know any resources on how to get started writing a plugin for Google's Picasa?  I love it for photo management, but I have some ideas for how it could be better.

- Riya-esque facial search:  given a large enough corpus of faces and pictures (people tend to be repeated often in individuals' albums (family, friends), I would think some semi-workable version of this could be done.  And with 13+ gigs/7 years of photos, it would be very nice for search.
- Upload to Facebook  EDIT:  [Someone already made a very nice version](http://apps.new.facebook.com/picasauploader/)
- Upload to any non-Google property, actually.

I know there are certain APIs and a Picasa2Flickr plugin out there, and I was wondering if anyone had seen any resources on this topic or had any experience

Answer (score 1):

there is a an [Opensource Project](http://picasa2flickr.sourceforge.net/index.html#about) which created a "Upload To FlickR" Plugin. Maybe you could use it as an startingpoint...

Answer (score 1):

I thought about facial recognition many years ago but my search only found a web API - no plugin api. My idea was to use an external facial recognition program to slowly index my entire catalogue of pictures and reliably tag them according to who was in them. It wouldn't need to be 100% accurate, but anything over 85% would be acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

I would start with the Picasa API:

[Picasa API](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/overview.html)